# How can I make quotation characters part of a string so discord can read it?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, quotes

I am currently working on a Discord bot and I am trying to inculde discord formatting in the reply of the bot, which is done like this:

```format

text

```

The problem is that the quotes are not part of the string that I want to send, like this:

````
if (args[0] === '2'){
    result = "```yaml\nText "+array.slice(0,2);"\n```"
    message.channel.send(result);
}
````

the var "result" and the array used in the code are created higher in the code but are not relevant to the problem

The first three quotes, before the format 'yaml' work, and when I trigger the bot these quotes get send in the response. The last three quotes don't work. I have tried to escape these characters but I have not had any succes.

How can I write the string so that the last ``` are included and get send to discord?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a "+" sign to concat the last part.

Comment: Thank you, that indeed fixed the problem.